# How to setup ruby profiler in IntelliJ

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

There seems to have been a recent update for to ruby mine that allows you to attach a rbspy profiler to a rails app. I have found a ton of guides on the internet ([for instance this one](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/cpu-profiler.html)) that explain what changes need to be updated in ruby mine to allow you to attach the profiler to the ruby process, but i have not been able to find the same steps for intellij with the ruby plugin.

Is there a way to perform the steps linked in the guide above in the Intellij IDE?

Comment: Have you tried the last IDEA 2019.2 EAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment Ruby profiler isn't available via Ruby plugin in IDEA but it's planned to be in 2019.2:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-23977

UPD: it seems to be available in the last IDEA 2019.2 EAPs (starting from 192.5118.30)